# Visual Studio 2022 processed tables, too much RAM

Tags: ssas, ram, tabular

We started to use SSAS models in our company. Instead of being precise on names I will explain the process, because I did not grasp much understanding yet.

We have tabular model which has oracle database as datasource. In visual studio we basically describe which tables will be further used and transform the data. This is deployed to SQL Server Management Studio where it's processed. To this server are connected end tools, like PowerBI etc.

I earlier discovered that you can process the tables in Visual Studio to see the data instantly (processed table directly in Visual Studio which loaded all the data into Visual Studio) instead of having to process via SQL Server and see on PowerBI. But since I processed all tables, some of them having X million rows, my Visual Studio is basically impossible to use, since its laggy and takes around 7g RAM. I realized that I need to somehow delete the temp data and do further settings. But having scrolled through internet, gpt etc I did not find good solution. Anyone with some insight?

That's how poorly introduced projects end.

Comment: Your question could use some code to elucidate how you are "seeing the data instantly," but it sounds like you should consider implementing [pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/paging-through-a-query-result) to take chunks of the table at a time and stay under the mem restrictions